# Pivot in C# with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following `LINQ` grouping clause. Where I want money divided into months. And it works but the money (Deckungsbeitrag - German format: `##,##`) is always 0. Am I missing to change format or something? I already tried different conversions in the following script:

```
  var results = (from r1 in table.AsEnumerable() group r1 by new {
          Geschäftspartner = r1.Field < string > ("Geschäftspartner"),
              Kunde = r1.Field < string > ("Kunde_KZ"),
              //Monat = r1.Field<string>("Monat")
      }
      into g select new {

          Kunde_Kz = g.Key.Kunde,
              Geschäftspartner = g.Key.Geschäftspartner,
              Jan = g.Where(c => c.Field < string > ("Monat") == "7_2017").Sum(c => Convert.ToDouble((c.Field < string > ("Deckungsbeitrag").Replace(",", ".")))),
              Feb = g.Where(c => c.Field < string > ("Monat") == "8_2017").Sum(c => c.Field < float > ("Deckungsbeitrag")),
              March = g.Where(c => c.Field < string > ("Monat") == "9_2017").Sum(c => c.Field < double > ("Deckungsbeitrag"))
      }).ToList();
```

**Edit**
The input table is like

> xyv|kut|23,45|7_2017|

So there can be null values for certain months on certain customer(Kunden) for the Money, so i tried this:

```
Jan = g.Where(c => c.Field<string>("Monat").Contains("/7_2017/")).Sum(c => (double?)c.Field<decimal>("Deckungsbeitrag")) ?? 0.0,
    Feb = g.Where(c => c.Field<string>("Monat").Contains("/8_2017/")).Sum(c => (double?)c.Field<decimal>("Deckungsbeitrag")) ?? 0.0,
     March = g.Where(c => c.Field<string>("Monat").Contains("/9_2017/")).Sum(c => (double?)c.Field<decimal>("Deckungsbeitrag")) ?? 0.0
```

But still only 0 values for money...

Output in the Grid:

```
Select KATHOPEGN2 "Katholische Kirchenstiftung ""Herz Jesu""" 0 0 0 
Select IMGAECREU1 "Landgasthof ""In Gaertlein """ 0 0 0 
Select 180GRGERA1 180 Grad-Event GmbH 0 0 0 
Select RASSFBETZ1 1a autoservice Rass 0 0 0 
Select ASDIEBAYR1 A. S. Dienstleistungen 0 0 0 
Select VEOANAK a.n.a. Kreislaufwirtschaft 0 0 0 
Select ABWASEGLO1 Abwasserzweckverband Trubachtal 0 0 0 
Select OELMEPEGN1 Adolf Oelmeier 0 0 0 
Select AECGMBADB1 AEC Alternative Energieconzepte GmbH 0 0 0 
Select VLLASPEGN1 Afrim Vllasalija 0 0 0 
Select AGIPSBAYR1 Agip Station Hoellrich 0 0 0
```

Comment: Firstly, did you check that `g.Where(c => c.Field<string>("Monat") == "7_2017")`  has any rows? by Debug.

Comment: I updated and used a contains clause. So it seems to work and I get back values for certain customers on certain months but only summed up to 0...

Comment: Can you show more details on the input, with column (field) names and values?